# Is it possible to restrict a Google Drive app's permissions to a specific folder(s) (and subfolders)?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, permissions

When installing an app for Google Drive, depending on the app, access to the filesystem is required and requested at the time of install.

Is it possible to restrict this to specific folders(s) and their subfolders?

For example a photo editor or diary app, or Notepad for Google Drive - https://drivenotepad.appspot.com/.

Why would such apps need to be able to access the whole filesystem?

Or even perhaps the user wants to simply restrict where the App can access.

If not it might not be a bad idea, security-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

At this time it's not possible to restrict access to folders, but its possible to restrict access to files.

## Remarks

Feature request should be directly send to Google. This could be done from Google Drive itself, Help > Send feedback, and/or through the Official Google [Drive Help forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/drive-es).

## References

[Security of Google Drive apps - Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2523079?hl=en)